# Gettimg Illegal State Exception On Button Click

Tags: android, onclick, illegalstateexception

**I am learning to make an android game and I have tried it many times but there is this same problem every time and my app crashes when I click on it and I have tried everything from my end. Help will be appreciated.**

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITyao.png)
[crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Ogq.png)

> **This is *Main Activity***

---

```
package com.example.connect3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// 0 = yellow, 1 = red

int activePlayer = 0;

// 2 means unplayed

int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

public void dropIn(View view) {

    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2) {

        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

            activePlayer = 1;

        } else {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

            activePlayer = 0;

        }

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360f).setDuration(300);

        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

                System.out.println(gameState[winningPosition[0]]);

            }

        }

    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
}
```

### **This Is Full Stack Trace**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.connect3, PID: 14521
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.connect3.MainActivity.dropIn(MainActivity.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This Is activity_main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `counter.getTag()` is returning null, which is to be expected, as `View`s do not have any tags set by default. Did you mean to add `android:tag` attributes to the `<ImageView>`s in the layout?

Comment: I dont't understand, I'm totally new to android development. Can you tell me something by looking at the code that I can try.

Comment: Are you telling to add something in Imageview in xml.

Comment: @MikeM. I think got what you were trying to say and applied it & it worked. Thank you for help.